# do i need cross validation for ordered logit model?

Tags: regression, cross-validation

I have a question about ordered and unordered logistic models for categorical data since I am new relatively, sorry if my question is basic. I read different sources and learn what should I do but I am confused about the order of what I should do;
I should first descriptive analysis of data, is the distribution of data also what I should care about when I want to choose the model?
2- should I do cross-validation first with the whole dataset? and after fitting the model should i evaluate the model again to find the goodness of fit? should i also split data to train/test datasets ?

i appreciate if you help me with the steps of fitting the model.

Answer (score 2):

The process of building a model requires one to understand a large number of issues.  Go back to fundamentals and study some texts and articles and case studies first.  See for example [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms).  You'll see that model specification is something that needs serious thought and subject matter knowledge, and that it is not wise to use the data to tell you which model to use.  In particular don't use the dependent variable Y to tell you which Xs to include as predictors.  Watch out for bad linearity assumptions.  Validate the final model using the bootstrap or 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation.   Avoid split sample validation unless N > 20,000.  Descriptive analyses are not helpful except for things like examining missing data patterns and extreme skewness in predictors that may lead to problems of robustness (i.e., we sometimes take cube root or log of a predictor before expanding it in a spline or regular polynomial).

Comment: “In particular don't use the dependent variable Y to tell you which Xs to include as predictors.”. I interpret this as saying if there is external logic to include a regressor, that is it is known a priori to affect the dependent variable, then include it. Is this correct, or is it broader than this? Or maybe avoidance of OVB perhaps somewhat justifies being non-conservative in regressor inclusion?

Comment: That's it, and don't do any "variable selection" as usually defined (screening variables or doing stepwise variable selection on the basis of p-values).   A very common mistake is believing that it's wrong to have a "non-significant" variable in a model.

Comment: @FrankHarrell  thank you for your help; can you please let me know how should i check about linearity in ordered logistic regression?

Comment: and if a variable in the model has a p-value that is not less than 0.05, should i not remove it from the model?

Comment: Correct.  Feel comfortable with so-called "insignificant" variables in the model as this signals that you are not double dipping.